# OS X 10.10.4 Yosemite, has the default PATH changed?

Tags: bash, homebrew, osx-yosemite

Today I had to configure a new macbook, running `10.10.3` out of the box and immediately upgraded to `10.10.4`.

After installing `homebrew` I went to configure the default `PATH`, and opened `/etc/paths`.

I found that it contained:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

that is, `/usr/local/bin` is at the top. This is not what I was expecting, and what I know should be the default.

Has the default changed? I reviewed the Homebrew installation script, and it doesn't seem to change `/etc/paths`. I also `stat`'ed the file, and it doesn't seem to have been changed.

So, is this the new default PATH order in OS X?

Comment: What do you know should be the default and how do you know it should be the default and not what the `/etc/paths` file says?  Personally, I take charge of my PATH and set it from first principles (and yes, `/usr/local/bin` is definitely not first (8 directories listed before it, in fact — but I live with some complex setups).

Comment: Not really a stackoverflow question imho... voting to move to superuser. As for the `PATH`, I generally just disable the `path_helper`. It gives me more problems than I care to have.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler in previous versions of OS X, `/usr/local/bin` is the last entry in the list, and I'm used to bring it to top manually by modifying `/etc/paths`.

Comment: OK.  So what's the problem?  The entry is where you want it.  It isn't where it used to be, so Yes, it changed.  What more do you want to know?

Comment: I wanted to know if the default changed or if something else has changed the file without me knowing. I am hoping to find someone informed on the subject.

Comment: maybe the installer "sensed" that you had modified the `/etc/path` and that it didn't need to make any additional changes? I would call that a feature ;-) Also, you're aware of the Apple specific stackexchange site -- http://apple.stackexchange.com/ ? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think the PATH value you show out is the default order.

My default order:

```
$ cat /etc/paths
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```